# Recursively extract contents of (nested) parentheses in string, replace selected content(s) down to a single (char+int), read again and repeat

Tags: string, c++11

This is my first post so please comment down if you need further clarification, Say we take in a string such as:

`((((a).(5)).((a)*)).((b)*))*`

and through the process, we perhaps count++ the amount of '(' read and count-- the amount of ')' read until we come across our first char or variable **(we can consider other operators such as '.' or '|' or '*')** that is the left and innermost content such that `a` is replaced so that our string now reads:

`(((R1.(5)).((a)*)).((b)*))*`

We must consider when a is selected, we also include its parenthesis as well but only consider the string that is read (perhaps store it in or as a vector, pointer, object, etc.), the same applies for when `5` which results in:

`(((R1.R2).((a)*)).((b)*))*`

at this moment we perhaps find now that the innermost content found is string `(R1.R2)` and
this results the string to be converted into R3 and having the string as:

`((R3.((a)*)).((b)*))*`

We continue the iteration for `a` to be read too.

`((R3.(R4*)).((b)*))*`

If a star `*` is read, we can consider extracting that content with `R4` to be replaced as `R5`

`((R3.R5).((b)*))*`

Our next iteration follows:

`((R3.R5).(R6*))*`

`((R3.R5).R7)*`

`(R8.R7)*`

`R9*`

and finally as our final result,

`R10`

And we end.

I've already tried a variety of algorithms from several sources for hours yet I'm still stuck and puzzled at the same spot and I may not be thinking this through very properly as I had hoped.

The only closest that was modified was this:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/extract-substrings-between-any-pair-of-delimiters/

but I'm still puzzled about what must be properly implemented.

How would you make this possible? Any solutions or a straight post of your code could surely help me understand this process.

Comment: I'm unsure about what you are struggling with. _"tried a variety of algorithms"_ sounds a bit random. Did you _understand_ the algorithms you tried? Have you tried designing an algorithm of your own?

Comment: What do you need as output - that sequence of intermediate strings? The strings which were replaced when each `R` value was substituted? A tree representation of the original string?

Comment: @TedLyngmo At the moment the I may be throwing in and out algorithms that don't work and I'm currently relooking them again for what each achieves. I tried my hand on developing my own however so far the stored variables have the wrong output shown, the contents were either shifted, grabbed too far, to short, or not display at all for the sake of reducing errors. You can assume what I've tried has little to go on so apologizes if what I'm saying is still to bland, and still trying to understand this as I go.

Comment: @aschepler The string that is currently read would overwrite itself with replace.() or any other method that you would prefer, and as such the same string would be read again, this time with changes that it came with it. You can add additional fundamentals like a tree representation to showcase the process or anything else that's fine. The **output** could just be the final result yes.

Comment: That makes it sound like you just need the final `R10`, which you could maybe get just from counting the total number of `(` and `)`.

Comment: Here is one possible way: https://onlinegdb.com/xbNK9mVW0  If that does what you want let me know and I will make an answer.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah You may have solved it here, you can post it here as a possible answer. Thanks